# Magento 2 in how to remove the frontend in products empty values?

Tags: magento2.2, attributes, products, magento-2.1.9

How to remove the products empty values ?

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using any custom phtml file to show these values? Post the file name with path which you are using to display these values or update the whole code of that file to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct()
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
            <tbody>                
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?> 
                <?php if($_data['value'] == 'N/A') {

                }elseif($block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label']))=="Is Featured"){

                    }elseif($_data['value']=='No'){
                    }else{
                    ?>                
    <tr>
        <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="col data yota-attribute-td" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <?php
    }  ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Its Working :)

Answer (score 0):

in

> app/design/frontend/[theme_vendor]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

find this section in line 24 :

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="col data yota-attribute-td" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just add

`<?php if($_data['value'] == 'N/A') continue;?>`
after

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
```

---

p.s If the mentioned file wasn't there you can create needed directories and copy attributes.phtml from magento core files:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

or you can just edit the core file in magento (not recommended)

Comment: it's not working in attributes.phtml page

Comment: did you make needed folders and path correctly? @SUDHAKARARUNACHALAM